# Not able to run maven command (mvn -version) through jenkins on mac machin but same command working fine for terminal of mac machine

Tags: ios, maven, jenkins, build, terminal

Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins6366168807637424809.sh: line 2: mvn: command not found
    Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE

I tried to change the path of Maven in Jenkins but it did't work .

I have set maven path on Global tool configuration.
Name-M2_HOME
Path-/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.0

[image: Global tool configuration.]

[image: Build commond]

Comment: Directory `/Applications` seems to be reserved for system-level applications. Jenkins might not have right to read it. Did you try to install Maven in somewhere under your home, such as `/Users/Ankit/Applications`?

Comment: I tried with that also it giving error.

Answer (score 0):

you should point the `PATH` to `bin` folder, like `/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin`

Comment: After putting path  "/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin" Global tool configuration.still facing this issue.

Comment: Please show the screenshot of your Global tool config for maven and your job configuration's screenshot in your question.

Comment: One more question,  your job is executed on the Jenkins Master? In your case, it's your Mac.

Comment: I have added image for both.Yes it is in jenkins master.